# Impliment UML Ternary Association in java Code

Tags: java, oop, uml, class-diagram, ooad

I'm currently having some trouble implementing ternary associations in Code. 
I get the binary ones, 
but I am unsure about ternary Associations.

this is typical scenario in a university.

Lecturer can teach a one subject to one or more students
student can teach one subject from only one Lecturer
Lecturer can teach one student to only one subject

There exists a ternary association between these three classes.

Relation among these three classes shown in below UML class diagram and also multiplicities are there

[image]

I've read on different sources regarding this all across the internet and coudn't find a solution

How do I implement the association between these three classes ? or, 
In general What are the possible ways to implement association between classes (in java) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, it depends.

The usual way to implement association classes is by using associative arrays. In your example you'd have (eventually) a combination of `Lecturer`/`Subject` to access a list of `Student`s. If your requirements are different you could for example return a list of `Subject`/`Student`s when supplying a `Teacher`.

When using a database you will have the primary keys of `Lecturer`/`Subject`/`Student` in a table `Teaching`. This allows for individual selects like for the ones mentioned above.

Some pseudo code out of my hat:

```
class Teaching {
  private Hash lectRef; // assoc. array 

  public void addTeaching(Lecturer lect, Student stud, Subject subj) {
    if lectRef[lect.hash] == None { lectRef[lect.hash] = []; }  
    // if none, default an empty array here
    // lect.hash is a unique hash code for the Lecturer object

    lectRef[lect.hash].append((stud, subj); 
    // tuple of student/subject referenced

    // if you need other fast results (e.g. subjects per student or the like) you need to hash them here too
  }

  public [(Stud, Subj)] studSubj (Lecturer lect) {
    return lectRef[lect.hash];  
    // returns the array of student/subject tuples
  }

  // add other result operations like subjects per student as needed
}
```

Comment: appreciate if you can provide sample code (dummy code ) for Lecture teach subject to student(s).

teach means assigned subject class to a class variable `learnedSubjectList` in student class

Answer (score 2):

according to Amadan 
i was prepare a answer

since i'm new to java , syntax can be incorrect
if this solution is wrong please correct me

```
//Lecturer class
class Lecturer{
    private List<Klass> klassList; 

    public List<Klass> getKlasses(Klass klassList){
        retrun klassList;
    }

    public List<Klass> addKlasses(Klass klassList){
        this.klassList = klassList;
    }

    teachStudents(){
        klassList = getKlasses()

        for (int i = 0; i < klassList.size(); i++) {
            (klassList.get(i)).teachSubjectToStudent();
        }
    }
}

//Student class
class Student{
    private Klass klass;
    private List<Subject> learnedSubjectList; 

    public void learn(Subject subject){
        learnedSubjectList.add(subject);
    }
}

//Subject class
class Subject{
    private Klass klass;
}

//Klass class
class Klass{
    private Lecturer lecturer;
    private Student student;
    private Subject subject;

    Klass(Lecturer lecturer,Student student,Subject subject){
        private this.lecturer = lecturer;
        private this.student  = student;
        private this.subject  = subject;
    }

    //implimentation of how subject was teach to a student
    public void teachSubjectToStudent(){
        this.student.learn(subject)
    }
}

//this class is use for code execution
public class TestA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer();
        Subject subject   = new Subject();

        Student student1   = new Student();
        Student student2   = new Student();
        Student student3   = new Student();

        Klass klass1 = new Klass(lecturer,student1,subject);
        Klass klass2 = new Klass(lecturer,student2,subject);
        Klass klass3 = new Klass(lecturer,student3,subject);

        List<Klass> list = new ArrayList<Klass>();
        list.add(klass1);
        list.add(klass2);
        list.add(klass3);

        //create association link between lecturer class and klass class list
        lecturer.addKlasses(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd model the association itself as an entity in its own right (can't call its class `Class`, as that's already taken by `java.lang.Class`; usually people name such a class `Klass`, as it's obvious what it refers to; you can also use your `Teaching`, if you wish). Then you just have binary associations between `Klass` and `Teacher`, `Klass` and `Subject`, `Klass` and `Student`. `Teacher` and `Student`, in this view, are not associated at all, except indirectly through their involvement with `Klass` (similarly with other pairs).

Comment: appreciate if you can provide sample code (dummy code ) specially for `Lecture` class `teach()` method and also it's delegation code located in `klass` class

Comment: Nope, we never talked about `Lecture` class (which to me would imply one specific period of time when all the entities involved in one `Klass` come together, but that's just me), and I have no idea what `teach` method is supposed to do (I don't think I can make a convincing artificial intelligence that students would listen to in five minutes on Stack Overflow :P ). I was talking in general on how non-binary relationships are handled in real life; but there's not enough specifics for me in the question to provide any code.

Comment: Lecture is the one who doing teaching.therefore `Lecture` class must have `Teaching()` method am i correct

Comment: I thought that was `Lecturer`.

Comment: sorry..

Lecturer is the one who doing teaching.therefore Lecturer class must have Teaching() method am i correct

Comment: Not really, but mostly because of conventions. First, methods in Java are in snakeCase. Secondly, property accessors by convention start with `set` and `get` (or `is`), and would be named in plural if the result can be a list. Since one `Lecturer` can teach several different instances of `Klass`, I’d call it `getKlasses()` (I’m not sold on “teachings”, sorry :p ). If you ignore conventions, `Teaching()` is fine, but then so is `Yoda__provides666YOGHURT____()`.